# How can I use left join with columns containing blank spaces in the name?

Tags: sql, join, left-join

Here's the first piece of my query, where I select three columns from the table ANP_Combustiveis:

```
select [MÊS],[PREÇO MÉDIO DISTRIBUIÇÃO],[PREÇO MÉDIO REVENDA] 
from ANP_Combustiveis 
WHERE PRODUTO = 'ETANOL HIDRATADO'
```

What I want to do now, is to use these fields in left join. For example:

```
select distinct [MÊS] from ANP_Combustiveis as A
left join 
(select [MÊS],[PREÇO MÉDIO DISTRIBUIÇÃO],[PREÇO MÉDIO REVENDA] 
        from ANP_Combustiveis WHERE PRODUTO = 'ÓLEO DIESEL S10') as B
    on A.[MÊS]=B.[MÊS]
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: What's wrong with your current query?

Comment: It's not working. Since I'm running this on R using RODBC there's not much information on the error message

Comment: Any data returns? Something to point out what is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only element missing is the alias in the firts column

```
select distinct A.[MÊS] from ANP_Combustiveis as A
left join 
     (select [MÊS],[PREÇO MÉDIO DISTRIBUIÇÃO],[PREÇO MÉDIO REVENDA] 
    from ANP_Combustiveis WHERE PRODUTO = 'ÓLEO DIESEL S10') as B
on A.[MÊS]=B.[MÊS]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix your problem, but the query is equivalent to:

```
select distinct A.[MÊS]
from ANP_Combustiveis A;
```

The `left join` is not doing anything at all, because a `left join` keeps all rows in the first table -- and that is where you are selecting the value.

If this query does not do what you want, I would suggest that you ask another question and provide sample data and desired results.